# I can not figure out how to install Raylib-Lua on Debian

Tags: lua, debian, google-chrome-os, raylib

I am trying to install a [lua binding of raylib](https://github.com/tsnake41/raylib-lua), but I cannot install it.

Nowhere online can I find instructions, hours of digging haven't helped. Wondering if anybody knows how to install on a fresh install of Debian 11 (Bullseye)

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like building is `git clone --recursive ...` and then `make`.  Does it work?  What errors have you got?

Comment: @ESkri external/glfw/src/x11_platform.h:32:10: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #include <X11/Xlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:656: rglfw.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tylerkmn/raylib-lua/raylib/src'
make: *** [makefile:53: raylib] Error 2           (ALSO, READ: I am on an x86_64 Intel Pentium Silver powered Crostini container)

Comment: The problem looks specific to `google-chrome-os`.  Please set this tag on your question.